# How to populate a drop-down based on another drop-down's result with ajax on a template file on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have 3 drop downs on my form and based on the user's choice one the first one the values from the second one will load.So, I try to populate a drop-down based on another drop-down response. And I get an error here (5 please see the code below); How can I solve it?

The code works on WordPress, "Twenty Twenty" theme, as a template file but if I change the theme it doesn't work

```
jQuery('#select_brand').on('change', function() { // occurs when the value of an element has been changed
    var brand = $(this).val();
    $('#models_select').html('<option>Select Model:</option>');
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/get_models_brand.php',
      type: 'POST',
        data: 'brand=' + brand,
      success: function(json) { 
        var models = JSON.parse(json); // (5)
            for(var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
                $('#models_select').append('<option value="' + models[i].bModel + ' ">' + models[i].bModel + '</option>')
            }
      }
    });
});
```

The get_models_brand.php looks like this:

```
$brand = $_POST['brand'];

$models = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT bModel FROM dr_vdb WHERE bBrand = "' . $brand . '"');

echo json_encode($models);
```

Then i get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.success ((index):228)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$(function(){
        $("#select_manufacturer").change(function() {
            $("#models_select").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/get_models_manufacturer.php?choice=" + encodeURIComponent($("#select_manufacturer").val()));
            $("#versions_select").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/reset.php");
        });
        $("#select_brand").change(function() {
            $("#models_select").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/get_models_brand.php?choice=" + encodeURIComponent($("#select_brand").val()));
            $("#versions_select").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/reset.php");
        });
        $("#models_select").change(function() {
            $("#versions_select").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/get_versions.php?choice=" + encodeURIComponent($("#models_select").val()));
        });
        $("#models_select").load(function(){
            $("#versions_select").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/get_versions.php?choice=" + encodeURIComponent($("#models_select").val()));
        });
});
```

and the gets should be:

```
$brand =esc_sql($_GET['choice']);
$models = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT bModel FROM dr_vdb WHERE bBrand = '$brand'",ARRAY_A);

echo "<option>Select Model:</option>";
foreach($models as $row)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['bModel'].'">'.$row['bModel'].'</option>';
}
```